# Can I add extra values to a global enum in a managed package when I create a new package version?

Tags: apex, managed-package, enum

I am thinking about adding an Apex enum to my managed package (1GP currently, though I suspect that's not an important aspect here). Before doing so, I wanted to understand whether or not it is possible to (later) add new enum literals/values to the enum in new major/minor releases.

I've had a search around the usual suspects, such as [Components in Managed Packages](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_packageable_components.htm) and [Metadata Coverage Report](https://mdcoverage.secure.force.com/docs/metadata-coverage), but these don't help since enum isn't even mentioned - I'm guessing it is equivalent to an Apex class from the metadata perspective - and as always the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_enum.htm) fails to tell you anything except the blindingly obvious.

Have you ever done this in a managed package? Could you add new values in new versions?

Comment: I can't point you to any official documentation that states that it can be done, but this is something we have done in our codebase over the years without a problem.

Comment: @PhilHawthorn add it as an answer; it's good enough for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule, you can always **add** new elements (e.g. new global methods, classes, values, etc), but you cannot **delete** any elements. In your case, that means you can add a new value, but you cannot edit/remove a value later, so make sure that's what you intend to do. For the purpose of the above statement, *editing* a value is the same as a delete and add, which would not be allowed.

Comment: Sometimes this isn't the case; e.g. in global interfaces you cannot add anything new. That's why I was erring on the side of caution to see if folks had actually done this. @PhilHawthorn's comment gave me that assurance.

Comment: @PhilW Oh, that's true. The interface thing is a weird exception, because, when you think about it, if you add a method, then every single subscriber's code would no longer be valid (it would not have the new method as required by the interface). The main rule is that you're allowed to make changes that have no chance of breaking subscriber code.

Comment: Indeed. What gave me pause on enums is that third party code might have a switch against the enum with no "when else", which would break their usage too.